# uwsgicluster - no live upstreams while connecting to upstream client

Tags: nginx, cluster-computing, uwsgi

Below simple nginx config for cluster, then I turn off `192.168.1.77:3032` server.

From time to time I catch 502 error and "no live upstreams while connecting to upstream client" in logs, while "server unix:///var/tmp/site.sock backup;" working and as I guess must handle request but nginx don't find it as live. What could be the problem?

nginx config:

```
       upstream uwsgicluster {
            server 192.168.1.77:3032;
            server unix:///var/tmp/site.sock backup;
        } 


server {
    listen      80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/sire.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site-error.log;


    location / {
            uwsgi_pass   uwsgicluster;
            include        uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

If I remove 192.168.1.77:3032 server
from upstream and restart nginx it works fine, but with switched off 192.168.1.77:3032 server errors occurs periodically

Comment: Is your remote upstream server always available?

Comment: What your building is effectively an load balancer. What about setting up application server(s) with uwsgi an nginx on top of them an then create this loadbalancing server which only job is to pass http 80 requests to your app servers (not uwgi requests).

Comment: Also this hotswapping on your loadbalancing looks like the perfect way to get your loadbalancing server down when your upsteam servers fail. Use an remote hotswap.

Answer (score 1):

I think that nginx will still try both of the servers in the upstream block even if one isn't working. When it fails to connect to one of them, it will try the other one, but will still log the error you are seeing.

By default, the proxy_next_upstream setting will try the next upstream server on error or timeout. You can override this:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Are you only seeing error logs, or are you also seeing undesired behavior/load-balancing?